# "No data available in table" is displayed though we have data in the html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

In my code I am creating two tables in same page and I am using dataTables.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.js scripts;

Unfortunately I am getting an error "No data available in table" and then its shows the actual data.

[image]

How to remove this? and If I click on "sort" in the table header I don't see any data in the table. As I understand no data was binded to Id "datatable-buttons"

```
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>

    <div class="x_content">
          <table id="datatable-buttons"   .....

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/category", function (data) {
           $.each(data, function(i, item) {
              var tr = $('<tr>');
              $(tr).append("<td>" + item.code + "</td>");
              $(tr).append("<td>" + item.name + "</td>");
              $(tr).append("<td>" + item.description + "</td>");
              $(tr).append('</tr');
              $('#datatable-buttons').append(tr)
          });
        });
      });
     </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables "No Data Available in Table"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852388/jquery-datatables-no-data-available-in-table)

Comment: Why not call the URL using the `ajax` option of DateTable....?

Comment: @adiga I am seeing the same problem on following the duplicate stackoverflow link too - I am sharing the code here - https://gist.github.com/viswesn/0308e1514dd0f7c59b6b291a0032dfc6 and it would be great if you can help me where I am wrong.  I feel that I am using more number of Javascript to load the page and it is not using the actual javascript to define the Id.

Comment: @vikscool Added Ajax functionality and still seeing the same result.  I shared the code in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

first your table must contain `thead` and `tbody`

```
<table id="datatable-buttons">
   <thead>
     <tr><th>...</tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

and then you must call DataTable functions after append all row to the table :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/category", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var tr = $('<tr>');
            $(tr).append("<td>" + item.code + "</td>");
            $(tr).append("<td>" + item.name + "</td>");
            $(tr).append("<td>" + item.description + "</td>");
            $(tr).append('</tr');
            $('#datatable-buttons tbody').append(tr)
        });
        $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable()
    });
});
```

Comment: I added <script> getJSON code ... </script> after closing the <table> ....... </table> as specified by you but then I am now getting error - $ is not defined

Comment: your script must be put after include the jquery script

Comment: I am still facing the "No data available" :) - I shared my code here - https://justpaste.it/61jqw